# wdio+jasmine reRun/retry single test spec it('',()=>{},3) doesn't work

Tags: wdio-v5, wdio-jasmine

I am using "wdio" with "jasmine" test framework and trying to reRun a single test spec following https://webdriver.io/docs/retry.html but retry is not happening. 
I am running following code using wdio sync runner like this - 
./node_modules/wdio wdio.conf 
It's executing the test only once.

```
describe("test suite", ()=>{
    it("test spec",()=>{
       console.log('inside test')
       fail('testing retry')
       },3)
})
```

I expect test should execute 1+3 times.but it executes only once. Retry is not happening. Am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

WDIO + Jasmine's retry behavior is a little strange, but it depends on your test's expectations. The following would retry the test three times.

```
it("Should retry", function() {
    throw "retry this test";
}, 3);
```

However, once an failing expectation (or fail() in your case) is added in, it will exit without retrying

```
it("Won't retry", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
}, 3);
```

This does not seem to be the behavior for a framework like Mocha, for example, so maybe the solution is to change frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that link is incorrect about what the third parameter to Jasmine's `it()` function means.

According the official docs, that number is the `timeout`, allowing you to specify how long the test is allowed to run before failing:

https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/global.html#it

Answer (score 0):

```
describe("test suite", ()=>{
    it("test spec",()=>{
       console.log('inside test')
       fail('testing retry')
       }, jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL, 3)
})
```

You need to add timeout interval, and number of retries after.